# Curl no longer executing after updating to PHP 7

Tags: php, curl

After upgrading to PHP 7 from 5.1 I Can't figure out why the curl is not executing.  The URL is legit, it never seems to execute and all returns are null.  I am probably missing something stupid but I have been hacking at it for a couple hours and thought I would ask.  Anyone see what's going wrong here?

```
    function makeCurlRequest($url)
    {
       echo "URL: " . $url . "<br>";
       $curl = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);                  // Feed curl url
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);          // Accept return xfers
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);          // Dont follow the redirect
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);          // Set time to inf
       $return = curl_exec($curl);                             // Sent request
       $httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);    // Grab HTTP Code
       echo "Curl Return: " . $return . "<br>";
       echo "Curl HTTP Code: " .$httpcode. "<BR>";
       return $return;
    }
```

People are asking if I remember to install it.  Im running on IIS, it seems to come in the windows binary package.  The php_curl.dll is included now and has it enable in the php.ini by default.

Comment: Do you have the curl extension installed?

Comment: Yep, when I run test code from other sources it seems to work.

Comment: After upgrading, it's possible you forgot to re-install `curl`. Double-check that it's installed, and **debug** in each step of the code.

Comment: In that case, definitely step through it with your debugger

Comment: should be helpfull: `print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));`

Comment: @rtfm Thanks for the heads up on using print_r with getinfo.  All seems to be correct there though.  Total head scratcher for me tonight.

Comment: Does the `echo "URL: " . $url . "<br>";'` line execute and output the correct url? I.E. Are you sure the function is being called?

Comment: @SteveE. Yes, those are normally not in the function, they were added for Diag.  The URL is outputing the correct URL, the $return and $httpcode are both return null.

Comment: Try using Postman or something to run the request outside of your code. Is the response what you expect?

Comment: @fubar Yeah, if I make the API call manually everything works fine.  I can copy paste the URL strait from the echo and all goes well.

Comment: @OmegaNine Okay. Have you confirmed that the URL is a direct URL and there are no redirects? You could try enabling the follow location option and see if that works.

Comment: @fubar The URL does redirect, but I dont need it.  The API call will, create an object, then redirect me to the page for the object after responding with a 200 httpcode.

Comment: This turned out to be a problem with the CA .pem file.  It was being stored in Program Files and the space was not being processed correctly.  After I moved it to PHP\ it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a problem with file names in the php.ini file.  The default directory for curl was in program files.  The space lead to issues when trying to locate .pem file for certs.  After moving the file to c:\php\ the calls were being made like normal.